java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project java.time.Instant to java.time.OffsetDateTime
In my spring application, I am fetching date from my PostgreSQL database.
The datatype of the date is created_at timestamp with time zone.
I have seen in the past and also mentioned in the documentation here, the appropriate data type for this date is OffsetDateTime.
However, when I am trying to fetch this date from my Projection class, I am getting below error:
public interface MyProjection {
    OffsetDateTime getCreatedAtDate();
}

Error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project java.time.Instant to java.time.OffsetDateTime; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found] with root cause","meta":{"error_code":"UnsupportedOperationException","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]"},"payload":{"error_stack":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project java.time.Instant to java.time.OffsetDateTime; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found

If I use java.time.Instant, the code works fine.
But for legacy reasons I have to use OffsetDateTime.
What am I missing?
Chatgpt suggests to use below property, but it does not work either:
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC


ZonedDateTime is a better class (than OffsetDateTime) as the same time offset can have a varying number of countries at a given time, say North and South America with  a mix of DST.

@JoopEggen, that might be true in abstracto but in fact that type is not yet supported officially by JDBC

As for the problem, it could be that the ORM is somehow mapping to an Instant, which can only be converted to OffsetDateTime with another parameter of a ZoneId. It might help to post the full stack trace

Neither Instant nor ZonedDateTime is mapped in JDBC. For a column of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, use OffsetDateTime. Write some plain straight JDBC code to retrieve from database, OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ). If that works, then study your Spring setup to find the errant mapping to Instant.

Have you read this sentence from the link you've posted? "When a timestamp with time zone is mapped to a java.time.OffsetDateTime, the Java value will always have a zone offset of zero (UTC)." This is because timestamp without time zone and timestamp with time zone are actually both stored using 8 bytes. In other words, no time zone data is actually stored in each row. The "with time zone" thing is pure metadata. So using OffsetDateTime is pointless. Just use Instant, and store the offset in another column.

So I ended up removing projection and using named query and dto, which solved my issue. Not sure what was the most appropriate solution here though.
